# JSF closing tag after a <script> section

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

In a jsp file, I would like to close a tag outside of a script section :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" lang="fr_FR" xml:lang="fr_FR">

    <head>      
        <title>titre</title>        
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            document.write('<b>');
        </script>

        </b>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The error message is :
**com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /login.jsp: Error Traced[line: 18] The element type "b" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".**

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think parser can be aware of such logic in javascript code, so probably your only option is to also close the tag the same way you open it.

```
<script>
    document.write('<b>');
</script>
...
<script>
    document.write('</b>');
</script>
```